# Dropdown to horizontal carousel jQuery plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, combobox, drop-down-menu

I am looking for any jquery/jquery-ui plugin to convert `select` html element (drop-down list) to a nice looking "carousel". Not image carousel, but something similar to jQuery-ui datepicker component title:

[image]

With side buttons that allow going through list items. Does anyone know anything similar to this.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for my misread. Deleted my answer, I understood you now and will look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own quick plugin instead.
http://jsfiddle.net/YxKFh/

If anyone know any existing plugin that does the same, please let me know, I'll mark it as an answer.

UPD: some [animation](http://jsfiddle.net/YxKFh/3/) added